# Show attribute filter in layered navigation only after another filter is selected

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

I'm trying to create a catalog with Magento that will list a lot of products which are made of different materials (over 15000 accross the entire catalogue) but they can be grouped like

```
metal -> iron, steel, copper, zinc, aluminum etc
ceramic -> clay, titanium trioxide, porcelain etc
amorphus -> glass, silicon etc
```

So I thought of creating a multi select attribute that will be filterable via layered navigation. However I'm encountering two problems related with that.

I can create an atttibute called

`material_group`

with let's say 200 groups and a multi select attribute called

`materials`

with 15.000 materials and the following problems arise.

1. In layered navigation at the catalog category page this would make
   magento load 15.000 materials and slow it down quite a bit as well
   as making the page extend way too much to the bottom so the user
   would scroll a lot.
2. In the admin page it's going to be really hard to sort the attribute values as new values are added so when creating a new product the person that has to select the materials would have to look for them in an unsorted multi-select list of 15.000 items.

In the frontpage:

currently if a user clicks on a `material_group`, the layered navigation will filter the products and less `materials` will show up in the next filter but I would like to force magento to not load the materials attribute values until a `material_group` has been selected and I have no clue how to achieve that.

In the admin page:

Ideally I would want the attribute values to be filtered by the grouping attribute so that in the multi select the options would be limited.

Any ideas what I should look into to make this happen? Or do you know of a magento extension that will allow parent/child relationship between attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice you to take a look at 
[Amasty layered Navigation](https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html)

Here is the option you are looking for looks like:
[image]

Comment: Hi, indeed this seems to advertise doing exactly what I need for this case. Thank you very much.